# Django global ManyToMany Relation (more than symmetrical)

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

I have trouble on how to make a ManyToMany relation where every object is connected to every other object.

Here's my example for better understanding:

```
class Animal(models.Model):
    animaux_lies = models.ManyToManyField("self", verbose_name="Animaux liés", blank=True)
```

If y have only two animals linked together, it works fine, thez I correctly linked together in both ways (because the relation is symmetrical).
But if I have 3 or more animals, I don't get the result I want. If Animal1 is linked to Animal2 and Animal3, I would like Animal2 to not only be linked to Animal1 but also to Animal3 (and Animal3 linked to 1 and 2).
How can I do that? Even with a through table I don't see how to do this correctly

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to represent graphs and ask questions about connections within those graphs.  That is extremely challenging using a relational database, which is what Django's ORM works with.  It is possible using a graph database, but that will require different libraries to query the data.